# Adding a function to wordpress theme to bypass/replace premalinks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Looking at Cssremix.com

when you hover over a item you can see the "Views" function I'm assuming they are using a plugin that links with the post views but when clicked the item redirects not to the post but to a website/site used

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](http://www.tomorrowland.com/2008/11/12/wordpress-simple-post-views-counter-plugin/) gives you the post views. To filter a link you can hook into certain filters, such as `post_link` or `the_permalink`.

Here are some docs:

- [Plugin API usage](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)
- [Filter reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)

The usage would be something like this:

```
add_action('post_link', 'do_custom_link');

function do_custom_link($url, $post) {
  $external_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'external_url', true);
  if($external_url) {
    return $external_url;
  }

  return $url;
}
```

This would get the external url from a [meta field stored with the post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), called `external_url`. You would define that meta field using the custom fields UI when you create the post through the admin pages.